# How to add trailing dots?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am making an application in which the label keeps scrolling up. The problem I have is I want to do right alignment so that I get "." in a sequence like

```
Basket..............
Ball................
keyboard............
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

I have tried this, but it isn't working for me,

```
for (int u = textBox1.Length; u = 40 ; u++)
{
    strDotsBuilder.Append(".");
}
```

Comment: I tagged this as C# since `strDotsBuilder` looks like a `StringBuilder` - if I am wrong, please correct it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to append "." to make the string a particular length? Or are you wanting to write activity indicators out to the console for a commandline application? or something else?

Answer (score 8):

That really doesn't needs to be in a for loop...
Why don't you use the [padLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) function of a string?

> "myString".PadLeft(40,'.');
>   Edit:
>   You need "myString".PadRight(40,'.');

Comment: Oh, yes :p (I need 15 chars to add the comment, so here's some rubbisch words :p)

Answer (score 1):

Stormenet's suggestion should point you in the right direction.
However when I see your example sequence, I'd probably go for the [padRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx) variant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int u = textBox1.Length; u < 40 ; u++)
{
    strDotsBuilder.Append(".");
}
```

The second statement in a `for` loop is the condition that determines whether or not to keep looping.  In your case you were assigning "40" to `u` rather that checking it as an upper bound for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your for loop is correctly written, since the second for-loop argument should be boolean resulting statement. Yours is not.

So instead:

```
for (int u = textBox1.Length; u = 40 ; u++)
```

you should write

```
for (int u = textBox1.Length; u <= 40 ; u++)
```

Comment: == is not the correct operator, either.  It should be <, as the second argument for a for loop is the condition under which you loop.  In your corrected sample, it will only loop when u is equal to 40.

Answer (score 0):

Using ellipses or full stops as a visual indicator will only work correctly in a console or other app using a monospaced font, and only then when the width of the label is sensitive to the user's system font sizes.

If you are creating a web app, you may have better luck with a bottom border style for your label to create that leading line, a right-floated image that clips at the edge of the label, or a repeating background image in the label's parent overridden by the label text.